# how to escape double quotation in terraform?

Tags: terraform, hcl

I am using the remote-exec provider in my terraform v0.9.11 template like this:

```
... 
 provisioner "remote-exec" {
     inline = [
       "Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -force",
       "./C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Config\Replace-FileString.ps1 -Pattern '""' -Replacement '"${var.admin_password}"' -Path LauchConfig.json"
     ]
...
```

But I get an `illegal char escape` error at `-Pattern '""'`.

The command I want to execute on the remote machine is: `"... FileString.ps1 -Pattern '""' -Replacement '"xyz"' "`

> PS: escaping with \ like `"... FileString.ps1 -Pattern '\"\"' -Replacement '\"xyz\"' "` does not work either.
>
> `...` represents omitted irrelevant text here.

Comment: From everything I can see, it looks like escaping with a backslash should work.  What actually happens when you try it - assume it's some sort of parser error?  If so, I wonder if this is a regression in terraform and should be logged as a new bug.  In the meantime, could you use the `script` option rather than `inline`?

Comment: @JamesThorpe when I have the backslash used, I still get `illegal char escape` .. I will try `script` and see if the problem persists

Comment: Was just looking at that - you might need to use the [`file` and `inline` since you've got an argument to pass in](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html#script-arguments) (`admin_password`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the error message was misleading when pointing to `-Pattern '""'` as the actual error turned to be in another location in the template where the backslash in a windows file path was not properly escaped (i.e. `C:\filename` when it should have been `C:\\filename`

The error message need to point at the right error location!